# Swift 3 and AVCaptureDevice depreciation, when trying to find Camera name

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-camera

I came across this problem, where I am coding Swift 3 in iOS9, because that's about as old as I expect most useful devices will be now. Not everyone has upgraded - or can upgrade to iOS10. My iPad Mini can't be upgraded.
I needed to get the name of the camera, and came across depreciated code when running in iOS 10 on my iPhone.
I found the answer in Objective-C and ran it through Swiftify. Presto.

```
Device name: Optional("Back Camera")
Device name: Optional("Back Camera")
Capture device found
Capture session running
Device name: Optional("Front Camera")
Device name: Optional("iPhone Microphone")
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is the answer to getting both 
The code running on ios9, and 10 up, to avoid depreciation of the device bit, 
and to return the name of the built in devices.

This is depreciated in 10.

> AVCaptureDevice.devices()

So the editor suggested I add the code you see here beginning.

> if #available ....

and printing the device localised names I cant' find documented anywhere. So I found this, and changed it to Swift 3 with [Swiftify](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/project/)

> NSLog(@"Device name: %@", [device localizedName]);

The code shown produces this

```
Device name: Optional("Back Camera")
Device name: Optional("Back Camera")
Capture device found
Capture session running
Device name: Optional("Front Camera")
Device name: Optional("iPhone Microphone")
```

Sorry if this is confusing - but the code following is pretty straight forward. Hope it helps.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //=======================

    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        if let devices = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back) {

            print("Device name: \(devices.localizedName)")

        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    if let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as? [AVCaptureDevice] {
        // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
        for device in devices {

            print("Device name: \(device.localizedName)")

            // Make sure this particular device supports video
            if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
                // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
                if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back) {
                    captureDevice = device
                    if captureDevice != nil {
                        print("Capture device found")
                        beginSession()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```